# How keep uicollectionview scroll at a direction without drag?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I want uicollectionviewcell move like things on assembly line.
Now I use

```
(void)scrollToItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath atScrollPosition:(UICollectionViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition animated:(BOOL)animated
```

in a method and in the last of method i make method call it self. 
But `UICollectionViewCell` move and stop and go on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UICollectionView inherits from UIScrollView, so you can use

```
// determine point, which you want to scroll
CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0, self.tableView.contentSize.height - self.tableView.frame.size.height);
// scroll to it, with custom animation duration
[UIView animateWithDuration:5 animations:^{
    [self.tableView setContentOffset:scrollPoint];
    // Also you can use scrollToItemAtIndexPath here instead of setContentOffset
}];
```